# iPhone application closes on IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have iPhone application and when it starts on iPad it just shows start image (Degault.png) and closes.

I feel it should be some common problem...can anybody help?

thankyou

Comment: Is this an application you developed, or a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 4):

When these types of things happen, open up Organizer with your iPad plugged in. Click on your iPad in the list, and then in "Crash Logs" tab on the right hand side. Select the appropriate crash log for the application (or as many as there are for that application that are relevant for you), and use the crash report to figure out where the problem is with your application.